# Cómo utilizo archivos mp3 en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy intentando hacer un app que me reproduzca una canción, pero el archivo mp3 que he subido, se ha cambiado como a un formato de texto y no se como cambiarlo y aunque lo elimine y lo vuelva a pegar sigue igual.

para ejecutar la canción fue así:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Rawayana_High);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

`
y se me abre una pestaña con el nombre del archivo "Rawayana_High.mp3" con esto (son más de 30,000 líneas de código así):

````
!#&),.0358;>@BEGJLORTWY\^adfiknpsvx{}��������������������������������������������������    Lavc58.34            $@     E�#�F=�                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ���d �  i     
     �      4�  ?�W&^�'��#"���J2�.�k�   Ba0 6 ,)    ��u������M{I����q����@9A������d ��PL�����|V���F��P�"Qqq�t�sm��*DJ<8�#P,ݿ�����6  ��4gI���I�D"�XC���4Gc
��E�O��L r� S '`��  �'M��
xDpD>����~ �>Lp���/�ߔx�q==@ @���``o~��I$KB^9 ��q'\ χaW�o���4'0� �x� 3��/�9;�X����������ʝ��E (H�"Rb�r�àeI~Q ���SݷK�(M�Jl�7%m���yp\�<ckWݍ�g\fK���Ӱ�)�
��0E�}8���D��fD��!�F�%�
�
,��a�c��P�B�d�4�[�Ф!�"Do��T8\8x�����?
�c�� .�a/�C�c�� 1yX-��B��BY�\�iEXZ  ���"��3ćo�Qݓa�"�豷܉]!|┼���¸�N8����(^��G�C�@)蕒$7�6�l�j�-��%`r�Hg�6��BC]Z�@^CB�{il�^.td&�B��0�=K�]�ks�>F0���R$�`-��8SǑ����e�\Ӊ0�&�y����N���z���M��#I)/0        Ȕ��e���q�.��sb�c��PK���I#hqʽ��'���p<h�RF�� ����$Xl(�D��B0��)j��7�W��J��1t�bю�̊�� "II������\����D� �e��/dr���q���
��3d%̙���!p<Ҹ*S3)�y�r������W^��&"�r��D%t����X��J��?_tK$�^j�%+=5��1tH�^:�z��l�$&�����4ej^����~�ŭA�r�W.fK�����mS.���K�E]�u�u�]�*�(W̾)��^T��V9�km��m�$�!  P�ʜ{�)�b�!—B9�ì�~5��DTj�p9��f!��FwT}Pm�  � ffp�4�<�*�U)!vՍ��c��݈�����H���bMa�}�����0��J�n.�7��~�Ɵ!k@�>�q��R�l&DZVih�)�jʚH��Ok�J�Cz)G/�1����I������   5���џ{Sc���=��8Tc4H�d�M)�؂On�j��7i�~ ���D
 ��{zH�\dI�q��d�K��m1���=������;�d��"p�<X+,���4�4&�X�4��9c�b�c,b�N�GR{^��_;��k_�9۷����i�a��f�G~z`�X`��<ȝX��QZ��X72�4YJ���)����J��] Ш���ٖj&3)��:&Ԭ٦�ޏn�|�U�i�?�BȖ�d�ȑ%`���Ll`!�����qs4
��k.�$\�4]f�B���b*�����F#F.���S��8.�3W�i\�LJ
�e�J;�Z�c�?�� ���~�Y1�Kf�:RL�
2h��h```
*
````

Comment: No es como si un archivo de música guardara la letra de la canción en su interior. El audio no se guarda como texto, sino que directamente en binario. Lo que vez ahí es el resultado de intentar abrir un archivo que no contiene texto. Entonces ves muchos caracteres raros. Lo mismo pasa cuando intentas leer un ejecutable con un editor de texto.

Answer (score 1):

El archivo de audio no es guardado como texto, evita tratar de abrirlo como texto y editarlo.

De acuerdo a tu còdigo el Mediaplayer reproducira tu .mp3 pero este lo debes ubicar dentro del directorio `/raw` (si no existe tienes que crearlo).

Debes tener un problema en tu proyecto ya que el nombre de tu archivo .mp3 que es `Rawayana_High.mp3` es incorrecto, cambia el nombre a minusculas ya que no esta permitido tener recursos en tu proyecto con letras mayusculas.

> Los nombres de recursos basados ​​en archivos deben contener solo
> minúsculas a-z, 0-9 o guión bajo

por ejemplo puedes nombrarlo como :

```
 rawayana_high.mp3
```

y cambiar tu còdigo de esta forma:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rawayana_high); 
mediaPlayer.start();
```